# How does request.POST data get propagated to a form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am currently working with nested formsets and, while going through the Django source code, am finding that I don't have any the more basic understanding of how newly created form data in request.POST data is propagated to a new form object.

### Question:

When new form data is injected into request.POST (via javascript for example), how does it get parsed and populated into a new Django Form object?

Comment: Have you already gone through the tutorial on forms and read the documentation?

Comment: I've went through the Django tutorial && forms documentation more times than I can count... I am creating a nested formset scenario and the forms have proven to be rather tricky to work with

Answer (score 0):

Django use the terminology Bound Form for a form with data and Unbound Form for a form that hasnt got any data yet.

A form goes over the `cleaning` steps to get its data, it will get the QueryDict with the GET/POST values, then just loop over them and run any specific clean methods on the data.

Its quite easy to understand the code if you want to read it yourself

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py

You cannot add data with javascript, javascript is client side only. you can POST up data from javascript to the server, but the server does not care what posts the data.